# NHibernate Session Custom Data

Tags: nhibernate

What I would like to do is to have the current user id in the Save,Update,Delete listeners I configured for NHibernate.

In my opinion, the best way would be to insert this info in the ISession object, and in the listener read this info. But there doesnt seem to be any place to do it.

One way is to implement the interface, however, I can't find any example or base class I can inherit from (ISession has too many members). Once I do my implementation, I know that the listeners can typecast and get the user id.

The app is ASPNET MVC2 with Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out better, I think.

I just created a wrapper that implemented NHibernate.ISession, so in my method:

```
public NHibernate.ISession OpenDataSession(int userId)
{
  return new SessionWrapper(SessionFactory.OpenSession(), userId, this);
}
```

This way in my listener, I just type-cast to SessionWrapper and get the UserId property.

It works great so far, my wrapper also implements IDisposable, so it should be ok.

Well if anyone know better, let me know.

UPDATE: As requested to provide more insight.

SessionWrapper class definition: Just implement NHibernate.ISession and remap all methods to wrappedSession (the first argument of the constructor), like:

```
    public DataStoreSessionWrapper(NHibernate.ISession wrappedSession, UserSession currentUser)
    {
    }

    public NHibernate.EntityMode ActiveEntityMode
    {
      get { return WrappedSession.ActiveEntityMode; }
    }

    public NHibernate.ITransaction BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
    {
      return WrappedSession.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
    }
```

The idea is, by using Ninject, you would Bind the NHibernate.ISession to this wrapper. Though this assumes that the UserSession object is also accesible by the container which is kind of true since the UserSession can be stored in the Session bag.

UPDATE2 (as I am evolving :D): I have another way to do it, which I think is better.

Instead of having a wrapper, what I have is an interface IUserSessionStore which has basically a single method: GetUserSession() that returns the UserSession object. This interface is in the constructor of all classes that need this information.

And by Ninject, I simply map this interface to a class called UserSessionStore_ASPNETSession that implements this by storing the object into the ASPNET Session Bag.

Obviously I'm assuming this is a website where everything is in a single tier (no remoting, or wcf involved).

I believe this is cleaner and faster to implement, and it also benefits all other layers that may need this info.

Thanks!

Comment: If you access the session by your own method anyway, you could create a SessionContext class, which *contains* as session and Data. I show you in my answer.

Comment: How can this work?? you should get an exception when you cast in the listner: something like Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl' to type SessionWrapper

Comment: @KatLimRuiz Please could you provide your SessionWrapper implementation?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a session per thread, you could store it in a thread static field:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static int userId;

public static void UserId { get { return userId; } set { userId = value; } }
```

To avoid carrying a value from one session to another by the thread-pool, you should reset the value at the end of the transaction (e.g. in a transaction commit-event).

Note: I'm doing this with great success. But I have wrapped it behind some services. There is only a single ThreadStatic field, which contains a self made TransactionContext, which contains the session and all the additional data I need.

---

When you access the session by your own method, you could use a SessionContext class instead. It requires to change the callers, but you don't have to wrap the session.

Something like this:

```
public class ISessionContext : IDisposable
{
  public ISession Session { get; }

  public SessionData Data { get; }
}

public ISessionContext CreateSession()
{
  return new SessionContext(SessionFactory.OpenSession(), new SessionData(user));
}
```

Comment: Not good because the ISession is what you get in the listeners which is where I need the SessionData object. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but my situation is different:

I have a `NHibernateSessionManager` which handles `ISession`, `ITransaction` etc etc

Then i used `CallContext.SetData` in the `NHibernateSessionManager` to save the editor entity and then I use `CallContext.GetData` to retrive it in the `IPreUpdateEventListener`, `IPreInsertEventListener`,`IPreDeleteEventListener`

CallContext documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx

in web context I use `HttpContext.Current.Items`